# How can I capture Touch Scroll on devices and emulate that on an element?

Tags: android, jquery

If I'm on a mobile device and I use my finger to scroll, how can I capture that scroll data with jQuery?

Comment: For user input have you seen this: http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html ?

Comment: Thanks fro the feedback, this looks interesting, but will this need me to install java or whatever else android needs on my server?

Comment: Than you can look at this http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/

Comment: Coincidentally I'm already using hammer.js :D

Answer (score 0):

For touch devices you have at your disposal  touchstart touchmove, touchend etc. which all are [TouchEvents](http://www.w3.org/TR/touch-events/).

You can attach a handler on `touchmove` event as you normally do with any other event type in jquery and measure the scroll position of the body or scroll element.

For example :

### JavaScript

```
$(document).on('touchmove scroll', function(){
  $('#touchDebug').text( $(this).scrollTop());
});
```

Here is the demo :

http://jsbin.com/uDegITe/2/edit

Answer (score 0):

Using hammer js I grabbed the deltaY and used scrollTop.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
     var element = document.getElementById("wrapper");
     var posX=0, posY=0;
     var hammertime = Hammer(element, {
        drag: true,
        swipe_velocity: 0.1,
        drag_block_vertical:true
    }).on('swiperight',function(){
         $(this).addClass('slidein');
    }).on('swipeleft',function(){
         $(this).removeClass('slidein');
    }).on('drag',function(ev){
         posX = ev.gesture.deltaX;
         posY = ev.gesture.deltaY;
         $('.snap-drawer').scrollTop(posY);
    });
});
```